# What can i use as collateral for a secured line of credit except my home

Tags: security, line-of-credit, borrowing

In Canada, a very common type of secured loan is a HELOC (Home Equity Line of Credit).

Now, what else except a home can I use as collateral for a Secured Line of Credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cars and homes tend to be the 2 things banks like as collateral.  Some bank will allow you to open a "secured" credit card by placing the credit limit of the card in a savings account.

If you're willing to get a little adventurous, you can also put up annuities, structured settlements, or lottery pay-outs in order to get a lump sum.  In general, you're better off taking the payments unless you have a good reason for a lump sum.  Some large bank will do this, but its not especially common.

Answer (score 2):

Effectively whatever the issuer of the line of credit is willing to accept. Some more common options are other real estate property, vehicles, CDs or savings accounts, annuities, etc.

It boils down to whatever the issuer is willing to accept and how they value the asset being used to secure the loan.